# print a pdf from an html div using javascript library jspdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I've got this function:

```
function printPdf() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
var elementHandler = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
var source = window.document.getElementById("page");
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
        'width': 180, 'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    });

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

}

It's called by oncklick on a button that if clicked returns to me a window asking me to choose an app from the store, but I've already installed a document reader what can I do?

Comment: I've tested the doc.save('./sample-file.pdf'); function but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just use `doc.save('anyname.pdf');`